# What is wrong with numpy.where function?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array (a list of 2 elements lists) `a` give below and I have a list of 2 elements `[30.94, 0.]` that I would like to look for.

When I did the following I don't get the desired result. Why?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[  5.73,   0.  ],
              [ 57.73,  10.  ],
              [ 57.73,  20.  ],
              [ 30.94,   0.  ],
              [ 30.94,  10.  ],
              [ 30.94,  20.  ],
              [  4.14,   0.  ],
              [  4.14,  10.  ]])

np.where(a==np.array([30.94, 0.]))
```

But I get

```
(array([0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]))
```

which is not true.

Comment: Question back at you - What do you expect with `a==np.array([30.94, 0.]`?

Comment: It should be `[3, 3]` for the indices of the rows and `[0, 1]` for the indices of the columns or something like this.

Comment: Nah I mean without `np.where`, just : `a==np.array([30.94, 0.]`. My idea is if you look at its output, you would have a better picture, hopefully.

Comment: Maybe `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Divakar hinted, `a == np.array([30.94, 0.])` is not what you expect.  The array is broadcast, and the comparison is done elementwise.  Here is the result:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

However, we can get what we want with `np.all`:

```
>>> np.all(a==np.array([30.94, 0.]), axis=-1)
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(_)
(array([3]),)
```

So you can see that row 3 matches, as expected.  Note that the usual caveats to using `==` with floating-point numbers will apply here.

Comment: To account for floating pt numbers, we can use `np.isclose()`, which allows `broadcasting`.

Comment: @kmario23 "broadcast" is a valid past participle for "broadcast".

Comment: @DietrichEpp I just realized that but it felt more natural to have it in `ed` form. Thanks for pointing it out, btw!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution but please be aware that this will be little bit slower than [Dietrich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291004/2956066), particularly for large arrays.

```
In [1]: cond = np.array([30.94, 0.])
In [2]: arr = np.array([[  5.73,   0.  ],
                       [ 57.73,  10.  ],
                       [ 57.73,  20.  ],
                       [ 30.94,   0.  ],
                       [ 30.94,  10.  ],
                       [ 30.94,  20.  ],
                       [  4.14,   0.  ],
                       [  4.14,  10.  ]])

In [3]: [idx for idx, el in enumerate(arr) if np.array_equal(el, cond)]
Out[3]: [3]
```